# How to utilize client-side includes in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

Is there a way to structure javascript/jquery by using an include() style of script concatenation similar to the way it can be done server-side in PHP?

I have a very long javascript engine that is currently embedded with dynamic code that ultimately comes from my database.

I want to separate the static js engine code from the dynamic js content code.

Wondering if there is a clever and "easy" way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply include other javascript files with javascript like this:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>');
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>');
```

Hope this suits you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @nmoliveira. I thought of that too. But actually you triggered me to think of this a bit differently so I now have an idea. Thanks for the tip and helping pull me out of the forest for a moment to see the trees.

Comment: Not the right way to structure javascript obviously but, I'm happy if this helped you!

Comment: What does `document.write` have to do with PHP?  :-)

Comment: @Cypher nothing to do of course. Initially I was thinking about a different approach and left that by mistake. I've edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).  These provide a way of breaking javascripts into requireable (importable) modules.

Comment: I see that `browserify` is an add-on or plugin. I could not tell right away if `require.js` is a plug-in or part of the core service @JackAllan

Comment: RequireJS is a set of JavaScript functions that allows you to "include" other JavaScript files at runtime.